# deploy LeadConvertSettings

Tags: deployment, ant

I'm new to ANT. I've seen some great threads on how to retrieve LeadConvertSettings, but I'm wondering if it is possible to deploy changes so that specific custom fields are no longer "mapped" (e.g. mapped to "None" in salesforce)?

I've tried listing out the specific fields in the package.xml and leaving the outputField empty, to an empty string, to a string "None".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">    
<LeadConvertSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <allowOwnerChange>true</allowOwnerChange>
    <objectMapping>
      <inputObject>Lead</inputObject>
      <mappingFields>
        <inputField>Emergency_Contact__c</inputField>
        <outputField></outputField>
      </mappingFields>
      <mappingFields>
        <inputField>Employer__c</inputField>
        <outputField></outputField>
      </mappingFields>
      <outputObject>Contact</outputObject>
    </objectMapping>
 <version>44.0</version>
</Package>
```

Using "None" or None in outputField results in this error: 1.  LeadConvertSettings/LeadConvertSettings.LeadConvertSetting -- Error: The field None in the Contactobject is missing or isn't visible to you.) . Leaving a blank outputField doesn't throw an error, it just does nothing.

Is this possible with ANT or do I have to do this manually? My ultimate aim is to delete custom fields, but have to "unmap" them first. I tried skipping that step earlier on and got a deployment error related to custom field being in used elsewhere in Salesforce.

I realize the delete aspect for the fields has to be done with destructiveChanges.xml (I'm clear on that part, just not how/if I can change these mapped fields to none first, a prerequisite for deleting them, so I can do this all via ANT).

Thanks in advance for any help/advice!